# Unique list of meta_values by multiple specific meta_key. Possible in Word Press?

Tags: php, wordpress

Thank you for reading my question.
I'm trying to show list of unique meta_value contained in multiple meta keys.  I could make unique list of meta_value from a single meta key, but being stacked since I tried to add values of one more another meta_key.

I tried to add some code following similar questions in this forum, but it does not work.

This is code I could achieve a unique list of meta_values belong to single meta?key('1st1' in this code).  I like to add meta_value belong to meta_key '2nd1' in this unique list.

```
<?php
    $posts =get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1, 
        'category_name' => 'dog_cat',
    ));

    if( $posts )
        foreach( $posts as $post )
            $species[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '1st1', true );
            $species = array_unique($species);
            foreach($species as $specie)
            echo $specie;
?>
```

Explanation

Meta_key named '1st1' contains meta_value like Chihuahua, American Cocker Spaniel, Wolf dog, American Cocker Spaniel.

Meta_key named '2nd1' contains meta_value like Chihuahua, Wolf dog, American Eskimo Dog, Wolf dog.

I like to list these dogs in one unique list like this.
American Cocker Spaniel American Eskimo Dog Chihuahua Wolf dog

I could make unique list of Meta_key named '1st1' by above code.  Now Im wondering how I can add another values belong to meta_key named 2nd1 into this list.

Comment: What is the result of get_post_meta, a single value? An array? What is `2nd1`? Also a string / array?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and sorry about my poor explanation and poor English.  I think I like to have a single value from each post.  Now, I added further explanation to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a relatively simple solution to your question but before I provide an example, I'd strongly encourage you to look at custom taxonomies. They're more than likely going to be a much better fit.

Let's break down the code you have now.

Firstly you use `get_posts()` which is going to return an array of posts. You're then looping through those posts and running `get_post_meta()` on each to retrieve a meta value. So far you're pulling one meta value per post but you'd like to retrieve a second as well. Finally you're running the array you've built up through `array_unique` to restrict it to a single occurrence of each term.

```
if ( $posts ) { // braces are important for your if/foreach statements
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $species[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '1st1', true );
        $species[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '2nd1', true ); // here's where we add the second post meta value to the array.
    }
}

$species = array_unique( array_filter( $species ) ); // here we're adding array_filter to remove empty get_post_meta results
```

Comment: It works!  It works completely what I wanted!  Thank you so much!!!  I could understand meaning of each code well by your comments.  I do appreciate your kindness!!!